# MVCContrib Html.Grid - how to set the colour of a row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a partial view;

```
        <%= Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
            {
                column.For(model => model.Date).Format("{0:d}");
                column.For(model => model.DayAmount);
                column.For(model => model.LeaveType);
            })
            %></div>
        <p><%= Html.Pager((IPagination)Model)%></p></div>
```

The latest requirement is to set the colour of the row depening on the leave type.
So I intend to add a colour column to the datatable, say LeaveRowColour.
When I Google search on MVCContrib I notice that maybe I should use the RowAttributes property to set this. But I am not clear how to do this, or whether I should find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom HTML helper to determine the CSS class to apply:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static string GetLeaveTypeCss(this HtmlHelper html, string leaveType)
    {
        if (leaveType == "Type 1")
        {
            return "t1";
        }
        else if (leaveType == "Type 2")
        {
            return "t2";
        }

        return "defaultType";
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<%= Html
    .RowAttributes(model => new Hash(@class => Html.GetLeaveTypeCss(model.Item.LeaveType)))
    .Grid(Model)
    .Columns(column =>
    {
        column.For(model => model.Date).Format("{0:d}");
        column.For(model => model.DayAmount);
        column.For(model => model.LeaveType);
    })
%>
```

Comment: That is certainly a solution that looks good. However I want to put a FontColour field in the database table so that if I put a new LeaveType in I do not have to change the program. That said, looking at your solution and the syntax of how to add a class, that may not be too hard if I can set a style in a similar way.

Comment: @arame3333, if you have a property name on your model which will directly contain the style then it is even easier, you don't need a helper, you could directly use this property.

Comment: That is what I am thinking. Something like model => Hash(@style => "FontColor:" + model.item.FontColor), although I am sure the syntax is wrong for this! I need to find out what Hash is all about in this context.

Comment: @arame3333, what's wrong with the syntax? Have you tried: `new Hash(@style => "background-color: " + model.Item.FontColor)`?

Comment: I decided in the end to put the whole style in the datafield so I can experiment with background-color and color. I think this is the best solution. Your help has been invaluable, so thank you for that.